# QT Text editor - Text is changed from last save?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a text editor using `QPlainTextEdit` with signal `modificationChanged(bool)` connected to slot shown below to know when text is changed from last save:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(modificationChanged(bool)), this, SLOT(codeModificationChanged(bool)));
```

slot:

```
void MyEdit::codeModificationChanged(bool change){
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Signal"),QString::number(change));
}
```

Documentation (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qplaintextedit.html#modificationChanged) says:

> **void QPlainTextEdit::modificationChanged(bool changed)**
>
> This signal is emitted whenever the content of the document changes in
>   a way that affects the modification state. If changed is true, the
>   document has been modified; otherwise it is false.
>
> For example, calling `setModified(false)` on a document and then
>   inserting text causes the signal to get emitted. If you undo that
>   operation, causing the document to return to its original unmodified
>   state, the signal will get emitted again.

My code is:

```
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("before"),QString::number(document()->isModified()));
    clear();
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("after"),QString::number(document()->isModified()));
```

Results:

- **before** msg: (show 0 - text not modified - is ok)
- clear() (activate slot, show 1 - text modified - is ok)
- **after** msg: (show 0 - text not modified - WHAT?)

How can command `clear()` to change the modification state without emit signal to `modificationChanged(false)`? In reality the signal code is more complex (change some variables, title bar...) and I need to know when that happens. Hmm... not only `clear()` command is behave like this, but also loading empty file or set empty text by using `setPlainText("")`. Those "reset" actions of text emit just one signal **modification state = true**, then set **modification state = false** without a signal. Remember that changing the modification state by using `setModified(bool)` always generates signal for `modificationChanged(bool)`.

Results for using `setPlainText(" ")` - with space instead of `clear()` or `setPlainText("")`:

- **before** msg: (show 0 - text not modified - is ok)
- setPlainText(" ") (activate slot, show 1 - text modified - is ok)
- new signal to slot (activate slot, show 0 - text is not modified - now is ok to tell me that QT choose to change the modification state)
- **after** msg: (show 0 - text not modified - is ok)

I am using QT 5.21. Do you think that is ok QT to change modification state to *false* without warning when I set empty text but tell me that when set non-empty text? How can I catch any change of modification state?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
diconnect(this, SIGNAL(modificationChanged(bool)), this, SLOT(codeModificationChanged(bool)));
clear();
connect(this, SIGNAL(modificationChanged(bool)), this, SLOT(codeModificationChanged(bool)));
```